# Decode JSON with Swift 5.2 throws error "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead."

Tags: arrays, json, swift

for several hours I cannot figure out what is wrong with my code. I checked my code and the internet many times but found nothing really helpful.
My problem is, I use the API of finnhub.io to get a JSON which I then want to decode properly. Everything is working fine except for the decoding which runs into an error. Please see the below code, maybe you can give me a hint, I am really out of ideas.

The JSON I get:

```
[{u'date': u'2019-11-07', u'symbol': u'AAPL', u'amount': 0.77}, {u'date': u'2019-08-09', u'symbol': u'AAPL', u'amount': 0.77}, {u'date': u'2019-05-10', u'symbol': u'AAPL', u'amount': 0.77}, {u'date': u'2019-02-08', u'symbol': u'AAPL', u'amount': 0.73}]
```

My SWIFT code looks like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct Dividends: Decodable {
    let dividend: Dividend
}

struct Dividend: Decodable {
    let date: String
    let symbol: String
    let amount: String
}

let json = """
{
    "date": "2000-01-01",
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "amount": "0.0"
}
""".data(using: .utf8)!

struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        Text("Text")
        .onAppear(perform: loadData)
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

func loadData() {
    let jsonData = json

    let url = URL(string: "https://finnhub.io/api/v1/stock/dividend?symbol=AAPL&from=2010-01-01&to=2020-12-31&token=xxx")!
    let urlSession = URLSession.shared
    let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in

        let dividends: [Dividend] = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Dividend].self, from: jsonData)

        for dividend in dividends {
            print(dividend.symbol)
            print(dividend.date)
            print(dividend.amount)
        }
    }

    // data task needs to be started explicitly via resume
    task.resume()
}
```

And the error message I get when running the app is:

```
Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)): file /Users/joe/Desktop/LoadJSON/LoadJSON/ContentView.swift, line 50
2020-04-25 14:02:33.682895+0200 LoadJSON[2347:102791] Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: Swift.DecodingError.typeMismatch(Swift.Array<Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.", underlyingError: nil)): file /Users/joe/Desktop/LoadJSON/LoadJSON/ContentView.swift, line 50
```

As far as I see it my JSON is an array with dictionary elements but I can't manage to decode it properly. Is my code really so messed up?

Comment: Why are you decoding a hardcoded single json entry instead of the downloaded data? Also if you want realistic testdata then surround it in a pair of `[ ]` since what you get back from the API is an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you should correct your test json as below,

```
let json = """
[
{
    "date": "2000-01-01",
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "amount": "0.0"
},
{
    "date": "2000-01-01",
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "amount": "0.0"
}
]
""".data(using: .utf8)!
```

OR use the actual `data` returned from the API as,

```
let dividends: [Dividend] = try! JSONDecoder().decode([Dividend].self, from: data!)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON should look like this:

```
let json = """
"Something" : [
{
    "date": "2000-01-01",
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "amount": "0.0"
},
{
    "date": "2000-01-01",
    "symbol": "AAPL",
    "amount": "0.0"
}
]

""".data(using: .utf8)!
```